# In Deuteronomy 33:12, which temple is being referenced?

Tags: deuteronomy

In Deuteronomy 33:12 (NASB)

> Of Benjamin he said,
>
> “May the beloved of the Lord live in security beside Him
>
> Who shields him all the day long,
>
> And he lives between His shoulders.”

As NigelJ points out in the comments

> God dwelleth the cherubim. But once the ark is gone and 'no more mention made of it' where shall he dwell ?

Is this a reference to the sanctuary of Shiloh (which would be in accordance with the unity of cult sponsored by Deuteronomy) or the sanctuary of Jerusalem (considered as being in the territory of Benjamin)?

Comment: You should explain why you think this refers to any sanctuary at all.  I cannot see any reference to the sanctuary, although some commentators do see an allusion to one but it required a textual emendation.

Comment: God dwelleth the cherubim. But once the ark is gone and 'no more mention made of it' where shall he dwell ? 'Between the shoulders', I would say. The capital 'His' is (to me) an imposition. It should be 'his' (Benjamin's) shoulders. Up-voted +1.

Comment: @Dottard just included more details

Comment: David lifted up his arms to God's holy oracle decades before his son Solomon built the oracle. Psalm 28:2.

Comment: Deuteronomy was written/recited before the settlement of Israel so it could not refer to either place.  That is why it can only refer to the tabernacle as it traveled with the people - only much later did it settle in Shiloh and later in Jerusalem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a reference to the sanctuary of Shiloh (which would be in accordance with the unity of cult sponsored by Deuteronomy) or the sanctuary of Jerusalem (considered as being in the territory of Benjamin)?

Ellicott believed that Moses prophecied the future sanctuary would be located in  Jerusalem in the territory of Benjamin:

> (12) And of Benjamin.—It is generally agreed that this blessing points to the site of the place which Jehovah chose out of all the tribes of Israel, **Jerusalem**, in the tribe of **Benjamin**. The Hebrew is divided thus:—
> “Unto Benjamin he said. Beloved of Jehovah!
> He (Jehovah) will dwell in security upon him,
> Covering him over all the day.
> And between his shoulders (mountain slopes) He
> hath taken up His abode.”

Cambridge Bible expresses a similar sentiment:

> his shoulders] The ridges of **Benjamin’s** territory: cp. Joshua 15:8; Joshua 18:13. Since P, Joshua 15:7; Joshua 18:15 f., Joshua 18:28, reckons **Jerusalem** as in Benjamin

Jamieson-Fausset-Brown also:

> of Benjamin he said—A distinguishing favor was conferred on this tribe in having its portion assigned near the temple of God.
> between his shoulders—that is, on his sides or borders. Mount Zion, on which stood the city of **Jerusalem**, belonged to Judah; but Mount Moriah, the site of the sacred edifice, lay in the confines of **Benjamin**.